# Why am I getting the message "node stack overflow" when the superclass is "VIRTUAL"?

Tags: r, r-s4

I am getting the message

Error in parent.frame() : node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow

when I try to construct an object using the S4 command "as", but *only* when a superclass is declared "VIRTUAL".

The class hierarchy is as follows:

PivotBasic contains Pivot contains Model

The setClass commands for Pivot and Pivot Basic and the constructor for PivotBasic are below. Class Pivot does not have a constructor. The Model constructor is too big to insert here.

This is really not a big deal (I think) because everything works fine if the "VIRTUAL" keyword is removed from the representation argument of setClass. But I am curious about the reason for the problem. Would anyone have insights on it?

Thanks,

Fernando Saldanha

```
setClass(Class = "Pivot", 
  representation = representation(
    pivotName = "character",
    pivotNames = "character",
    pivotData = "data.frame",
    "VIRTUAL"
  ),
  contains = "Model"
)

setClass(Class = "PivotBasic", 
  representation = representation(),
  contains = "Pivot"
)

pivotBasic <- function(
  portfolio,
  assets,

  controlVariableList,

  pivotData = NULL, # pivotName is ignored if pivotData is not null
  pivotName = "N_WEEKDAY_3_6",

  firstPredictionDate = as.Date(integer(), origin = "1970-01-01"),
  name = NULL,
  tags = "Event"
) {
  if (missing(portfolio)) stop("[PivotBasic: pivotBasic] - Missing portfolio argument")
  if (missing(assets)) stop("[PivotBasic: pivotBasic] - Missing assets argument")
  if (missing(controlVariableList)) stop("[PivotBasic: pivotBasic] - Missing controlVariableList argument")

  object <- model(
    portfolio,
    assets,
    controlVariableList,
    firstPredictionDate,
    name,
    tags)

  # The error message happens when this command is executed
  mdl <- as(object, "PivotBasic") 

  # Other code

  mdl
} # end pivotBasic
```

Comment: What does the model function do, and why aren't you using `new("PivotBasic", ...)` ?  You're more likely to get help if you produce a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a minimal example that illustrates your problem

```
.Model <- setClass(Class = "Model",
  representation=representation(x="integer")
)

setClass(Class = "Pivot", 
  representation = representation("VIRTUAL"),
  contains = "Model"
)

.PivotBasic <- setClass(Class = "PivotBasic",
  contains = "Pivot"
)
```

This generates an error

```
>     as(.Model(), "PivotBasic")
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.0 Patched (2013-04-15 r62590)"
```

but might generate an error like you see under an earlier version of R. This [thread on the R-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-October/065024.html) is relevant, where a solution is to define a `setIs` method such as

```
setIs("PivotBasic", "Model", 
  coerce = function(from) .PivotBasic(x = from@x), 
  replace = function(from, value) {
      from@x = value@x
      from
  }
)
```

I think of `setIs` as part of the class definition. If there are many slots needing copying, then a further work-around might be, in the replace function,

```
nms <- intersect(slotNames(value), slotNames(from))
for (nm in nms)
    slot(from, nm) <- slot(value, nm)
from
```

but the underlying issue is really in S4's implementation. A cost to removing the "VIRTUAL" specification is that it compromises your class design, and presumably the formalism of the S4 system is what motivated your choice in the first place; maybe that's not such a bad cost when faced with the alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. However, if my class has many slots (which is the case) then I have to do as suggested for each slot. Also, if new slots are added or deleted I have to modify the call to setIs. Are there any disadvantages in not declaring the superclass as virtual?

Comment: I updated the answer with a more general strategy for the replace function.